# Are there downsides to nesting data in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have data of different dimensions, for example:

- Name by Company
- Stock prices by Date, Company
- Commodity prices by Date & Commodity
- Production volumes by Date, Commodity & Company

We're thinking of the best way of storing these in BigQuery. One potential method is to put them all in the same table, and nest the extra dimensions.

That would mean:

- Almost all the data would be nested - e.g. there would be a single 'row' for each Company, and then its prices would be nested by Date.
- Data would have to share at least one dimension - I don't think there would be a way of representing Commodity prices in a table whose first column was the company's Name

Are there disadvantages? Are there performance implications? Is it sensible to nest 5000 dates + associated values within each company's row?

Answer (score 4):

It's common to have nested/repeated columns in BigQuery schemas since it makes reasoning about the data easier. Firebase produces schemas with repetition at many levels, for instance. If you flatten everything, the downside is you need some kind of unique ID for each row in order to associate events with each other, and then you'll need aggregations (using the ID as a key) rather than simple filters if you want to do any kind of counting.

As for downsides of nested/repeated schemas, one is that you may find yourself performing complicated transformations of the structure with `ARRAY` subqueries or `STRUCT` operators, for instance. These are generally fast, but they do have some overhead relative to queries without any structure imposed on the result at all.

My best suggestion would be to load some data and run some experiments. Storage and querying both are relatively cheap, so you can try a few different schema shapes and see which works better for your purposes.

Answer (score -4):

Updating in Bigquery is pretty new, but based on the public available info [BigQuery DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) it is currently limited to only 48 updates per table per day.

> Quotas
>
> DML statements are significantly more expensive to process than SELECT
>   statements.
>
> Maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per table: 48 Maximum
>   UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per project: 500 Maximum INSERT
>   statements per day per table: 1,000 Maximum INSERT statements per day
>   per project: 10,000

Processing nested data is also very expensive since all of the data from that column is loaded on every query. It is also slow if you are doing a lot of operations on nested data.

Comment: I also wanted to point out that processing of nested data is not expensive in BigQuery, since it was built around supporting nested and repeated data.